# php sdk authorization/form submission - firefox

Tags: facebook, forms, firefox, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

Starting late this week, I stopped being able to submit forms with some of my apps using the PHP SDK.

The problem is that forms won't submit, but (mostly) only on Firefox. Here's the story:

- My facebook site is `apps.facebook.com/nameofsite`
- The page on my server is at `www.mysite.com/somepage`
- When I go to `apps.facebook.com/nameofsit`e and submit a form, Facebook performs an auth check and redirects with `?state=asfsadfsf&code=asdfasfas`
- But when I do it on `mysite.com`, it submits properly.
- Also, if i go to `apps.facebook.com/nameofsite` on Chrome or Safari, they post properly. It's only on Firefox that I have an unescapable loop.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: what you mean by unescapable loop??

Comment: What version of firefox? And what are you doing in auth check? EDIT: I have experienced it before and do every two weeks or so.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi - sorry, that was poorly phrased. the unescapable loop is because the permissions redirect takes the user back to the same page. so you hit submit, it loses its permissions, and redirects back to itself as if you had never submitted.

Comment: @AshwiniDhekane - Firefox Mac 8.0.1. And the auth check is a function that checks to see if the user is logged in, and if not it sends him/her to a getLoginUrl. The flow I'm experiencing is that upon submit (from apps.facebook.com canvas page to the mysite.com page specifically), it registers as not having a user, so it redirects to the loginUrl (back on apps.facebook.com). Then it recognizes that it does have a user, and continues on its way. But it never submits. What have you noticed? Why does it show up every two weeks? That's pretty troubling, right?

Comment: PS As of 3:47pt, it started working again with no code change from me. At 3:46, I got the same redirect. At 3:47, it submitted properly. Why, and what can I do to prevent it in the future? I have no idea.

Comment: @Matt As of now I don't have solution for this and would love for an answer. I have narrowed the problem down to getSession returning NULL. If session is null i redirect user to getLoginUrl which redirects (already) logged in user back to application page, which shows the content at canvas url of my app.

Comment: @AshwiniDhekane That's exactly what I get as well, although it's the new getUser instead of getSession. It returns null, goes to getLoginUrl, realizes it's logged in and redirects to the redirect_url. If I figure anything out I'll post it back here.